# Why my bullet destroy immediately and not when will collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm studying Unity for the first time and I've a problem with my shot...

My bullet destroy immediately and not when will collider.

This is my bullet code:

```
public class BulletController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float bulletSpeed;
    public Rigidbody2D theRB;
    public Vector2 moveDir;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        theRB.velocity = moveDir * bulletSpeed;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);

    }

    private void OnBecameInvisible()
    {

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

When I play my game, the shot stop immediately.

If I remove this function:

```
  private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);

    }
```

then the shot start but it never collider. :(

Someone could help me ?

Comment: probably because its triggered by the player? Do some debugging.. print out what it hits..

Comment: how can I dot it ?

Comment: Find a basic unity tutorial, teaching you how to do really simple things is really beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: Does your player object has regid body component? If does, probably like @BugFinder said, it is triggered immediately when you shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Debug.Log(other);` in the `OnTriggerEnter2D()` to see who triggered the collision. If it's something you don't want it to trigger, but unavoidably enters the trigger, put the `Destroy(gameObject);` in a `if(collider != <something>){}`